# Book where a boy and 10 small dragons enter a wizard school

Tags: story-identification

The boy is found by a old wizard, and based on his patronage, he journeys to and enters a wizard school, with his 10 (small as cats) dragons that have adopted him and he must care for. The other initiates at the school are jealous of him, for 10 dragons are unheard of to own at one time! He ends up having dangerous adventures and some of the dragons give their lives defending him. Similar to the *Earth-Sea* series, in feeling...

Comment: Some similarities to [Dragonsinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonsinger) from the Pern series.

Comment: Yes! I think that is it! Thank you! It has been a really long time since I read it, and forgot a lot of the main story, but how it started really impressed me. Yes, it was a girl, that is why she had misgivings about entering the school and was not accepted right away.

Comment: Laura, you *really* need to re-read Dragonsinger: Menolly is a musician, not a wizard, and characterizing her as having "misgivings" about entering the Harper Hall is... well, "not even wrong" comes to mind.

Answer (score 11):

The actual details are almost completely different, but this sounds like a misremembering of *[Dragonsinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonsinger)* by Anne McCaffrey.

- "The boy" is actually a girl named Menolly.
- The "10 small dragons" are, at this point, 9 fire lizards - she doesn't acquire #10 until later. But yes, many important people on Pern are scrambling to acquire even a single fire lizard, so a young girl from a remote seahold who has 9 of them is, well, unusual, and a cause for envy.
- The "wizard school" Menolly enters is Harper Hall, which is Pern's arts and humanities institution, though the main focus is on music. (There's no outright magic on Pern: the dragons and their abilities are presented as naturally-occurring. The closest that Pernese humans come to magic is the telepathic bond between a dragon and its rider, but Menolly is not a dragonrider.)
- The "old wizard" who finds Menolly is Masterharper Robinton. Again, not a wizard, but I guess "patronage" is accurate enough.
- The other students, especially the girls at the dormitory where Menolly is initially lodged, are indeed jealous of her, but it's about equal parts her musical talent (genius, really), her back-country roots, as well as her fire lizards.
- Similar to Earthsea - well, female authors, fantasy*, written in the 1960s-70s... I suppose you could call them similar. Ish.

The details that *don't* match, no matter how I squint and tilt my head:

- There are no truly dangerous adventures to speak of, certainly not in *Dragonsinger*. In a later book, Menolly and Robinton do go on a sailing trip that ends up being more than they bargained for, but it all comes out OK in the end.
- I definitely don't recall any of Menolly's fire lizards giving their lives for their mistress. They do try to "defend" her, but mostly from "threats" such as someone making her angry - nothing truly life-threatening.

<sup>* Pern turns out to actually be science fiction, but *Dragonsinger* doesn't get into the pseudo-scientific underpinnings all that much.</sup>

Comment: I think part of the asker's confusion may come from conflating _Dragonsinger_ with _Dragondrums_. It'd explain the gender mixup and the part about the dangerous adventures.

Answer (score 9):

The OP replied to a comment of mine that this is correct, even though many of the details are off.

[Dragonsinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonsinger) by Anne McCaffrey deals with Menolly, a girl who enters the Harper Craft Hall on Pern, after wanting to do so for the whole previous book but being told she couldn't.  She does have 9 fire lizards, which had been nearly mythical until she found the clutch she impressed.

Comment: Oops... I just spent 40 minutes writing pretty much the same answer. To be fair, when I read the question, I immediately thought "this could be Dragonsinger except literally none of the details actually match"...

Comment: @Martha No worries, just saw that the OP had agreed so tried to do something from my phone.  Had no idea you answered, too (doesn't automatically refresh on the phone).  Yours is the better/more complete answer.